# Looping for creating a grid in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have to create a 50x50 grid of hexagons. I have an unordered list and each hexagon is a list element. Is there any way I can write a javascript function that creates the grid instead of me creating 2500 HTML elements?

Each hexagon has the following structure:

```
<li class="hex">
    <div class="hexIn">
        <button class="hexButton" type="button" (click)="move()"> </button>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Are there limits on what you're allowed to use?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. We have to use angular2 as framework though

Comment: I'd try to use `ngFor` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505233/does-ngrepeat-exist-in-angular-2

Comment: Could you give me an example? I am quite confused, as you can use ngFor to iterate over a list from a TypeScript file, but I do not really know how I can handle it with all the different tags...