# The ng-repeat value is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get certain elements from JSON object to display in my html, but I cannot do so in my app.
What I'm doing:

1. get JSON from steamAPI in my service (success, i can see the whole JSON in console.log)
2. pass the JSON from service to my component (success, if `*ngIF=items` is failing, the browser shows nothing)
3. I try to get `market_hash_name` and `icon_url` from the JSON with the code `<li ng-repeat="(key,value) in items.rgDescriptions">` (failure, ng-repeat works, but browser shows me ERROR TypeError: "_co.value is undefined")

   `<p>{{ value.market_hash_name }} <button>Add to your list</button></p>`
   this fails

I made a try-it example in w3schools to try the ng-repeat function.
I copied the JSON into the example (had to shorten it to fit) and it works.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZ6HYMY2YP2P

The example works on w3, but when I paste the same code (I literally pasted the whole thing at some point) into my project it fails with `ERROR TypeError: "_co.value is undefined" error. It seems the problem is in my project but I cannot find it.

How do I fix this problem?

My code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-itemlist',
  templateUrl: './itemlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./itemlist.component.scss']
})
export class ItemlistComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }
  
  items: Object;


  ngOnInit() {

    this.api.getItems().subscribe(data => {
        this.items = data;
        console.log(this.items);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

```html
<h1>Users</h1>


<ul *ngIf="items">
  <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in items.rgDescriptions"> 
    <img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/{{value.icon_url}}" class="img-responsive" />
    <p>{{ value.market_hash_name }} <button>Add to your list</button></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ngRepeat exist in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505233/does-ngrepeat-exist-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **`ng-repeat`** with angular, you need to use **`ngFor`** instead,

```
 <li *ngFor="let (key,value) of items.rgDescriptions"> 
    <img src="http://cdn.steamcommunity.com/economy/image/{{value.icon_url}}" class="img-responsive" />
    <p>{{ value.market_hash_name }} <button>Add to your list</button></p>
  </li>
```

Comment: I tried to use ngFor, but it doesn't work with objects, just arrays. Do i need to convert the json to array?

Comment: yes you need to use ngFor over array , in that case chang (key,value) to be just yourName and then access properties

Comment: for it to work i needed to add pipe (because ngFor doesn't support objects)

Comment: `<li *ngFor="let item of items.rgDescriptions | keyvalue">` this worked for me, thanks for your help :)